# Why I get NoneType for specified type

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a simple question with a simple script. I am actually working with matrix-like  value (like this one: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`).

On the file Input, reading from a file I actually get a `NoneType` although I defined the name at the top of the function. Here is the script of what I am doing:

```
with open("matrice.txt","r") as fichierMatrice:
    a_matrice = [] # name defined
    print(a_matrice)
    for line in fichierMatrice:
        print(line)
        a_liste = line.split()
        a_matrice = a_matrice.append(a_liste) # error here
print(a_matrice)
```

`matrice.txt` has the following content:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

at line 11 I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.append` returns `None`. When you do the following `append`, you are assigning `None` to `a_matrix`. That will cause the exception on the next  iteration of your loop.

```
a_matrice = a_matrice.append(a_liste)
```

The fix is quite easy. Just remove the assignment.

```
a_matrice.append(a_liste)
```

Comment: Thank's for pointing that out to me. That fixed my problem :3

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` is a built-in function that that returns nothing, therefore the `None`.

```
>>> lst = []
>>> new = lst.append(8)
>>> lst
[8]
>>> new
>>> print new
None
>>>
```

Instead, just remove what you are assigning:

```
with open("matrice.txt","r") as fichierMatrice:
    a_matrice = [] # name defined
    print(a_matrice)
    for line in fichierMatrice:
        print(line)
        a_liste = line.split()
        a_matrice.append(a_liste) # error here
print(a_matrice)
```

The same thing applies with `.sort()` and `.insert()`:

*`.sort()`:*

```
>>> lst = [9, 8]
>>> lst = lst.sort()
>>> print lst
None
```

*`.insert()`:*

```
>>> lst = [9, 8]
>>> lst = lst.insert(0, 7)
>>> print lst
None
>>>
```